# VS2010/MSBuild 4.0 building external projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build, msbuild

It seems that since VS2010 and MSBuild 4.0, VisualStudio and MSBuild are able to resolve and build project references that are not located within the solution.

Let us create an example to be more concrete. Create a solution called *Solution1* with a C# project named *A* and another project called *B*. In *project B*, add a reference to *project A*. Now create a new solution called *Solution2* and click "Add Existing project" and select *Project B*. There is a warning that can be seen in Solution Explorer and the Warning List.

The trick is that even with "warning as error" we are able to build *Solution2.sln*. Actually, *project A* is found 
and built by Visual Studio or MSBuild. Let us verify this by opening a VS2010/VS2012 command line and execute the following commands:

```
msbuild <dirPathToSolution1> Solution1.sln /t:clean **cleaning up solution1 with project A"
msbuild <dirPathToSolution1> Solution2.sln /t:build
```

*ProjectA* is effectively built and worse: the warning mentioned above is not even raised there. With previous versions of Visual Studio such situation could not happen (I have tested it with msbuild 3.5 and VS2008).

However, in our situation we would like to prevent such things. Indeed, we have a large source repository with several solutions and many committers. We are reorganizing our dependencies aiming finally to the extraction of smaller repositories. Meanwhile, we do not want developers to add hidden project dependencies without seeing it. We would like to allow only project references "inside" a solution, leaving other dependencies to assembly references.

So the question is "Is there a way, to prevent such solution such as Solution2 to build ?". Ideally, it should not compile with both VS2012 and MSBuild. However a solution involving only the MSBuild command line would do thanks to our Continous Integration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "The referenced component 'X' could not be found." considered a warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166831/why-is-the-referenced-component-x-could-not-be-found-considered-a-warning)

Answer (score 1):

**edit** I checked Microsoft.Common.Targets and there does not seem any way to achieve what you want. Either project references are built, or they are not (this is for instance influenced by the BuildProjectReferences flag of my original answer). There is no way to build them selectively depending on which solution they are in unless I'm missing something - which is mainly because project references are set on the project level, not on the solution level: in your project file there is an MsBuild ItemGroup named ProjectReferences and that is used. (Actually this makes some sense: if you ask MsBuild to build projectB.csproj, and B says it references A, then no solution comes into play and you could expect it to build A, after all you are referencing it).

Now as I understand it, you want to prohibit referencing across directories whose structure happens to be represented by solutions. If that is the case, and you really need this, you could probably get away with a tool that parses the MsBuild log and looks for lines like

```
Project "somedir\projectB.csproj" (2) is building "someOtherDir\projectA.csproj" (3) ...
```

then extract the directory info from it and make the tool raise an error when they do not match. Then incorporate the tool in your CI server and feed it with the msbuild log files.

**original answer**
Try with `/p:BuildProjectReferences=false` on the command line. As the name suggests it will disable building of referenced projects. When building solution1, this should not be a problem since projectA will be built anyway as it is in the solution. However when building solution2, it won't build projectA and you'll get a build error.

Comment: We have checked this msbuild option. However, this is not what we want. Indeed, we want to keep the project references resolution within the solution, excluding workaround involving build orders.
For example, a solution with two projects (in this order) ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2 then if, ClassLibrary1 references ClassLibrary2, the solution will not build with /p:BuildProjectReferences=false.

Comment: *Now as I understand it, ... represented by solutions*. You are guessing right that is more or less what we would like to prevent before we setup a cleaner separation. We have checked as well in MSBuild and found nothing for this situation. Maybe we will implement something to do the job... However, VisualStudio is raising a warning which means that there is somewhere in Visual a check for this situation maybe there is a way to reuse this...

Comment: Thing is, in VS loading a project is done using the classes found in the Microsoft.Build.Evaluation namespace (or something like that, don't know by heart), so it's not a build warning from MsBuild. Meaning if you want that warning, you'll have to get it manually yourself..